# Translations in Prestashop when DEFINE variable used

Tags: php, translation, prestashop

E.g. when I defined define(MYTEXT, 'My Text') and use this in a Prestashop module $this->l(MYTEXT), it works fine (so I can seperate large blocks of text in a separate include file).

But when I use Translations (Tools) for another language, every such text where DEFINE variables are used do not show up anymore ?

So I have no idea to translate these in another language, maybe a construction with the md5 encoding will not be recognized ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using the define for the text translations? But it will make things more complex. Just place the text in the module like

```
$this->l('Your text here');
```

and thats it, you can translate that text to as many languages as you want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "l" function in `classes/module/Module.php`

```
abstract class ModuleCore
{
    public function l($string, $specific = false)
    {
       ............
    }
}
```

so child classes extend from `ModuleCore` can use function `l` for translation text.
in your case, you should use function `$this->('your text')` in your module class.